# findstr search string not working

Tags: windows, cmd, findstr

I have a question regarding findstr which I hope someone can assist with.

I would like to perform a search piped from "net user" which can search for number of strings in the output. Those strings can be specific words or and specific phase.

Specific words are not a problem and works a treat but when combined with a specific phase the results are not as expected.

Below is a extract of the command which is pulling a variable from a for loop (%%a).

```
2>NUL net user /domain "%%a" | FINDSTR /I /C:"2221" /C:"deprovisioned" /C:"disabled" /C:"Account active               No"
```

FINDSTR /I "2221" "deprovisioned" "disabled" works no problem.
But I need a 4th string added at the end which unfortunately contains lots spaces.
When added the 4th search string it's simply missed from the search results.

Can anyone provide any advice?

Comment: Maybe look at powershell which provides more features...

Comment: That search with spaces should work fine. Are you sure the search is correct with the correct number of spaces?

Answer (score 0):

I've converted to Powershell and problem solved.

Thank you for your input.

skothk